# Is it possible to disable stack traceback in Lua?

Tags: c, lua, stack

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable stack traceback in the standalone Lua interpreter, use `debug.traceback=nil` in your Lua program.

Answer (score 1):

By calling the code in question via pcall or xpcall, you can handle errors however you want, including ignoring them completely.